# How to filter build_runner input by extension?

Tags: flutter, dart, build-runner, sourcegenerators

I am trying to make my custom builder using Dart's https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen.

The buildExtensions in `builder.dart` is `.dart`

It builds for any dart file

`buildExtensions = {          '.dart': [generatedExtension]..addAll(additionalOutputExtensions)        },`

[image]

So even if in build.yaml, I set the build input to `.source.dart`

```
  functionUnwrap:
    import: 'package:my_generators/my_generators.dart'
    builder_factories: ['functionUnwrapBuild']
    auto_apply: dependents
    build_extensions: {".source.dart": [".unwrapped.dart"]}
    build_to: source
    applies_builders: ["source_gen"]
```

It ignores the `".source.dart"` and still runs on any dart file.

Comment: I need to do this too. Did you find a way? My builder generates `.keys.dart` files and I want to process `.dart` files but ignore `.g.dart` files.